# How to calculate % of a polygon that is covered by another polygon

Tags: python, geolocation, geocoding, polygon

I have a set of polygons, each one as a dictionary in python (coordinate points conforming NON convex polygons) and i would like to know what % of one polygon is covered by every other polygons.

I want to make an example to make it clearer. I have different delivery coverages accross a city and i have the polygons of the different neighbourhoods of that city. My question is how do i know what % of each neighbourhoods i got covered.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: What assumptions do we get? Are all the inner polygons guaranteed to be entirely inside the outers? Is an inner polygon restricted to one outer polygon, or do some `delivery_coverages` span multiple `neighborhoods`?

Comment: i have no clue where to start to be honest, i was hoping there is already a package that does this.  A delivery coverage can cover multiple neighbourhoods as well. None of the polygons is entirely inside the outers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many complications to what you require.

1. Longitudinal length between points decreases with latitude.
2. Do polygons overlap or is one fully contained within another.
3. Does any polygon cross over itself.

In your case item 1 can be ignored in most cases.

If polygons don't cross and one is fully contained within the other the following javascript function can be converted to python.

```
function polygonArea(X, Y, numPoints) 
{ 
  area = 0;         // Accumulates area in the loop
  j = numPoints-1;  // The last vertex is the 'previous' one to the first

  for (i=0; i<numPoints; i++)
    { area = area +  (X[j]+X[i]) * (Y[j]-Y[i]); 
      j = i;  //j is previous vertex to i
    }
  return area/2;
}
```

Where X & Y are the coordinate arrays.The results of the two polygons then used for %.

If any of the coordinates cross the prime meridian the coordinates,of all polygons, will have to be standardised.

If actual areas are required the calculations can be quite complex.

Acknowledges to [**Darel Rex Finley**](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_area/) for function.

[**Here**](http://gleniffersystems.net46.net/polygon/polygonArea.html) is a demo on Google maps showing % area of pink polygon within green polygon. Here pink polygon is within green polygon.